# Apache HTTP Server stops working for only a certain local website

Tags: php, apache

I work with a few local websites, but some time ago one of them started causing these errors when I try to use it. I couldn't find time for it and left it, so I can't tell what change started causing this.

This is the problem signature:

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.12.0
  Application Timestamp:    54c90386
  Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.6.8.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   552ee66a
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0002a796
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: 1318
  Additional Information 4: 13181ae637ac2592fac0ca2dd662cdcc
```

It does not appear on the home page, but appears and prevents page load when viewing user profiles, also appears when viewing a single post. Only the header manages to load and it only shows this message:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3374
```

This is the relevant part of functions.php (I have added a comment behind line 3374)

```
function wp_list_pluck( $list, $field, $index_key = null ) {
    if ( ! $index_key ) {
        /*
         * This is simple. Could at some point wrap array_column()
         * if we knew we had an array of arrays.
         */
        foreach ( $list as $key => $value ) { /* THIS IS LINE 3374 */
            if ( is_object( $value ) ) {
                $list[ $key ] = $value->$field;
            } else {
                $list[ $key ] = $value[ $field ];
            }
        }
        return $list;
    }

    /*
     * When index_key is not set for a particular item, push the value
     * to the end of the stack. This is how array_column() behaves.
     */
    $newlist = array();
    foreach ( $list as $value ) {
        if ( is_object( $value ) ) {
            if ( isset( $value->$index_key ) ) {
                $newlist[ $value->$index_key ] = $value->$field;
            } else {
                $newlist[] = $value->$field;
            }
        } else {
            if ( isset( $value[ $index_key ] ) ) {
                $newlist[ $value[ $index_key ] ] = $value[ $field ];
            } else {
                $newlist[] = $value[ $field ];
            }
        }
    }

    return $newlist;
}
```

Does anyone know what causes that error or how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just added..

ini_set("memory_limit","64M"); at top of wp-config.php

Comment: @VasimVanzara I added it too, the error stopped appearing, then I noticed I also had `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` at the end. Then I removed `ini_set("memory_limit","64M");` and the error still doesn't show. Aren't these two lines supposed to do the same thing?

Comment: are working with which server?xampp??

Comment: @VasimVanzara Yes, on the fatal error message it shows I am using xampp. This problem appeared for at least a month, now I only added `ini_set("memory_limit","64M");` to wp-config.php and then removed it. I didn't even restart apache. I literally did nothing and it stopped appearing.

Comment: you mean it does not start xampp

Comment: Change port to 85

Comment: access it again.

Comment: It's a memory problem. Navigate to `xampp\apache\bin\php.ini` and increase the `memory_limit` constant.

Answer (score 1):

First open your wp-config.php which is located in the root WordPress directory. Then add the following line inside the main php tag:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

We just increased the memory limit to 64M. If you still get the error after this fix, then please contact your host. Most likely, they would have to go in their `php.ini` file to increase the memory limit for you.

If you are working on xampp then edit php.ini .Search `“memory_limit”` in your php.ini, and change the value of it. If no `“memory_limit”` found, add the following line at the end of php.ini

```
 memory_limit = 128M ; /* Change the 128M to your needs */
```

- Save file.Restart Apache.

**Note:You can find xampp/php/php.ini**